# Changing input value of a form and submitting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<!-- assume jquery is loaded -->
<body>
    <form id="sform" method="get" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="eid" />
        <input type="hidden" name="returnURL" />
        <input type="hidden" name="returnID" value="ieid" />
        <select id="dropdownlist" name="ieid">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What happens is the user enters an email address, it checks (server-side with PHP) the credentials and if valid, returns the following JSON object (in this case, assume that the values are valid urls (ie. `http://sitehere.com/somethingelse`):

```
{
  "get_action" : "geturl",
  "eid"        : "eidurl",
  "return_url" : "returnurl",
  "option_url" : "optionurl"
}
```

This is retrieved when the user hits the `login` button on the home page. This button triggers a `POST` request which retrieves the results and parses the JSON into the form above. I then change the values of the form from the original code and the action of the form itself before submitting the form. This is shown below.

```
$.post('/?c=controller&a=method', {'email' : $('input[name="email"]').val() }, function(data){
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#sform').change_action(result.get_action);
    $('input[name="eid"]').change_val(result.eid);
    $('input[name="returnURL"]').change_val(result.return_url);
    $('select[name="ieid"]').find('option:selected').change_val(result.option_url);
    $('#sform').submit();
};
```

Where `change_val()` and `change_action()` are defined like this:

```
$.fn.change_val = function(v){
    return $(this).val(v).trigger("change");
}

$.fn.change_action = function(v){
    return $(this).attr('action', v).trigger("change");
}
```

The reason why I defined these functions was because originally, I had just been calling `val('new value');` and the form seemed to not be updating at all. I read that I had to trigger a change when using jQuery to update the form before submitting it.

However, even after triggering a change, it seems like the HTML still isn't updated (at least in Chrome) and the form is not being submitted correctly because none of the values are actually changing.

So, I need to be able to take a parsed result, update the values in the form (with specific id's), and then submit the form so that it re-directs somewhere. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: When you define `change_val` & `change_action`, `this` is bound to (presumably) the window.  You will want to bind them to the appropriate object when you call them.... or just do `$('#sform').val(result.get_action).change()`

Comment: @Tibrogargan hmm doing something like `$('#sform').attr('action',result.get_action).change()` doesn't seem to work still (after updating the attribute values of each input and then calling `.change()`). After calling `.change()` I should be able to open up the HTML inspector and see these changed values, correct? I'm not really seeing anything right now and the form doesn't seem to submit with any information :(

Comment: Did this code worked outside `$.post` function? Try to use it with some non-variable values and post results here :)

Comment: @ChristianValentin Yep, previously the form had hard-coded values, and when the user hit a button, `$('#sform').submit()` was called. This worked, but for security reasons, we didn't want to leave the urls out for everyone to see. This is why we return them.

Comment: Don't know what browser you're using but doing this in chrome: `$('#button').click( function() { $('#form').attr('action', "new value").change() } );` works as expected

Comment: @ChristianValentin I've also used `console.log()` and compared all the return values with the ones that were previously there. There seems to be no difference. It's just that when using jQuery and `.val(value)` it doesn't actually want to update stuff.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Edit: I forgot that I should be applying the click to the button and not the outer div, that seems to work. I'll update some code to see if the rest of the values will change. Thanks!